# Bounding inradius, given circumradius.

Tags: triangles

The problem in my book is as follow.

> In a $\Delta ABC$ , if $r=r_2+r_3-r_1$ and $\angle A >\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ , then the range of $\dfrac{s}{a}$ is equal to: (Here $r_i $ are exradii)

I used the fact that $r_1+r_2+r_3=4R+r$ , to arrive at $r_1=2R$
After I used the fact that area by exradius and inradius are as $\Delta=r_1(s-a)=rs$

After simplifying one can arrive at $\dfrac{s}{a}=\dfrac{2R}{2R-r}$

Now Maximum value is easy to find as , I assume which seems true for time being.

Distance between incentre and circumcentre is given by $d=[R(R-2r)]^{1/2}$

I can find from this that $r<\dfrac{R}{2}$ surely.

Which gives $\dfrac{s}{a}<\dfrac{4}{3}$

But , I am not having a good idea  for lower bound of expression $\dfrac{s}{a}$ , for which i need to bound inradius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a $\Delta ABC$ , if $r=r_2+r_3-r_1$ and $\angle A >\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ , then the range of $\dfrac{s}{a}$ is equal to?

As $r_1+r_2+r_3=4R+r$. $$\implies 4R+r-2r_1=r\implies r_1=2R$$

Also $r=\dfrac{\Delta}s;r_1=\dfrac{\Delta}{s-a}$. So $$\Delta =rs=r_1(s-a)\implies(r_1-r)s=r_1a\implies \frac sa=\frac{r_1}{r_1-r}=\frac{2R}{2R-r}$$

Now: $$r\le R/2\implies \frac sa\le\frac43$$ 
Now:
$$r=4R\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2>2R\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2\tag{$\because \angle A >\dfrac{\pi}{3}$}$$

Now what if $A\to(\pi/3)^+$ and $B\to(2\pi/3)^-$ and $C\to0^+$, Now $r\to0$. You won't find a smaller value, because if it would exist, it needs to be negative and negative sines are not possible with half angles of a standard triangle. So:
$$\frac sa>1$$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{s}{a}\geq \frac{4}{3}$ :O

Comment: @Mann $r\le R/2\implies -r\ge -R/2 \implies 2R-r\ge 2R-R/2=3R/2$ Now $2R/(2R-r)\le2R/(3R/2)=4/3$

Comment: No i mean shouldn't it be $\leq$ ?in answer.

Comment: @Mann typo happens *:)

Comment: I am not sure the exact relation i was finding mad expression but i also had an conclusion somehow that $\frac{s}{a}$ didn't approach 1 , not sure  now might be just wrong at that moment.

Comment: Ahahah :D I know

Comment: @Mann why not and yes the edit has been made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23542/discussion-between-mann-and-adg).

Answer (score 1):

only an idea: $$\frac{s}{a}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{a+b+c}{a}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{b+c}{a}\right)>1$$ since $b+c>a$

Comment: I have thought of lower bound as 1 but that actually implies $r\rightarrow 0$ in the expression in terms of inradius and circumradius. I am not sure though if that would be valid , Since R should be disappearing as well, but there's also a angle given , I wonder if it can help.